# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'

Tags: django, testing, error-handling

Im trying to run tests on my site and i get this error message. Was wondering if anyone else has experience with this. May be with the Django Framework.

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace

Comment: There is absolutely no way to answer this question as you have not shown the code you are using or the full traceback.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you've added your module to the wrong list.

You need to add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list but you've added it to the `MIDDLEWARE` list.

Answer (score 3):

You have put your module which looks like **name.apps.NameConfig** in the wrong list ( maybe on the *MIDDLEWARE*) instead of *INSTALLED_APPS*

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing the `self` argument but can't be sure because not enough info was added. Please post the full stacktrace.